# How to get an image and text inside a icon side by side?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I want to get an small png image and some text side by side in an icon how to achieve that currently it's vertically there?
[This is the order I currently have want to get the two along side instead of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGj72.png)
the division is itself different because these are in a different subclass inside this messagecontent class.

Comment: Please add your current codes.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS flexbox.
Sample code :

```css
.image-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:#eee;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  border-radius:1rem;
}

.image-wrapper img{
  height:2rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
 }
 
.image-wrapper p{
  font-size:1.8rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src = "https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-icon-png-transparent-background-osteopathy-16.png" alt="logo"/>
  <p>Some random text</p>
</div>
```

Refer this to learn more about CSS flexbox [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Why not put that in a runnable snippet to show the example? (no downvote from me, only a suggestion)  Use the `<>` icon on the editor.

Comment: Thanks @PaulT. for the idea. I have done the same.